# Insert text at the start of a document in Word - openXML

Tags: c#, sharepoint, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am using OpenXML to manipulate Microsoft Word files (.docx).

I am sending the Word files as memory stream, editing them and then send them back to browser so they open in client office program.

I want to insert text, approximatley 10 lines, at the start of a document which already got content. I am doing it like this;

```
using (var wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(mem, true))
{   
    Paragraph firstParagraph = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Paragraph>().First();   


    Run run1 = new Run();
    Text text1 = new Text();
    text1.Text = "Document type: ";

    run1.Append(text1);

    Run run2 = new Run();
    Break break1 = new Break();

    run2.Append(break1);
    ProofError proofError1 = new ProofError() { Type = ProofingErrorValues.SpellStart };

    Run run3 = new Run();
    Text text2 = new Text();
    text2.Text = "Document ID";

    run3.Append(text2);
    ProofError proofError2 = new ProofError() { Type = ProofingErrorValues.SpellEnd };

    Run run4 = new Run();
    Break break2 = new Break();
    Text text3 = new Text();
    text3.Text = "Document Title";

    run4.Append(break2);
    run4.Append(text3);

    firstParagraph.Append(run1);
    firstParagraph.Append(run2);
    firstParagraph.Append(proofError1);
    firstParagraph.Append(run3);
    firstParagraph.Append(proofError2);
    firstParagraph.Append(run4);

    Paragraph paragraph3 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphAddition = "0068718C", RsidParagraphProperties = "0068718C", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00E1050C" };

    Run run5 = new Run();
    Text text4 = new Text();
    text4.Text = "A";

    run5.Append(text4);

    Run run6 = new Run() { RsidRunAddition = "00126F2D" };
    Text text5 = new Text();
    text5.Text = "tlet";

    run6.Append(text5);

    paragraph3.Append(run5);
    paragraph3.Append(run6);

    Paragraph paragraph4 = new Paragraph() { RsidParagraphMarkRevision = "0068718C", RsidParagraphAddition = "00E1050C", RsidParagraphProperties = "0068718C", RsidRunAdditionDefault = "00E1050C" };
    BookmarkStart bookmarkStart1 = new BookmarkStart() { Name = "_GoBack", Id = "0" };
    BookmarkEnd bookmarkEnd1 = new BookmarkEnd() { Id = "0" };

    paragraph4.Append(bookmarkStart1);
    paragraph4.Append(bookmarkEnd1);

    SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties() { RsidRPr = "0068718C", RsidR = "00E1050C", RsidSect = "000C7A63" };

}
```

My problem is that if I already got some text from the first line, then my text will be appended after the original text there. How can I push the original content some lines down, and insert my text above?

Answer (score 3):

Use `PrependChild<T>` instead of `Append`. `Append` will always be inserted at the end of the current element. So if you already have content in the first paragraph your append will put your text at the end. You can also insert your text as a new first paragraph by calling `Document.PrependChild<Paragraph>(firstParagraph)`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Maarten. Do you know how I can add a lineshift/enter in my text as well ?